# Mountain Lion Broke Firefox - Cannot Download Files

Tags: macos, firefox

Ever since upgrading to Mountain Lion I have had endless problems with Apps and firefox. My current issue is that I am unable to download files using firefox ever since the update. I get a messagebox saying the error

> /Users/username/Downloads could not be saved, because an unknown error
>   occurred.
>
> Try saving to a different location.

Comment: NP.  Have you tried changing the default download location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the download location, I proceeded to restart my computer and it appears to be working now.

Comment: This may suggest permissions problem with the Downloads folder. Try to verify and fix permissions (Utilities, then Disk Utility)

Comment: I've seen similar errors when the Profile folder inside ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles has incorrect permissions.

Comment: @lupincho that found lots of incorrect permissions, repairing now.

Answer (score 1):

Once again, the problems are not with permissions. In Firefox's preferences, on the general tab, Set Firefox to "Always ask me where to save files" under Downloads. Files will download fine, to the Downloads folder or anywhere else.